# Why bzr branch keep on being killed?

Tags: emacs, bazaar

I am trying to branch the emacs trunk:

```
$ mkdir emacs
$ bzr init-repo emacs
Shared repository with trees (format: 2a)
Location:
  shared repository: emacs
$ bzr branch bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk trunk
Killed39KB  2666KB/s | Fetching revisions:Inserting stream
```

After launching the `bzr branch` command, the download begins, after a while it is killed and the trunk directory is empty. Relaunching the same command does not help, it seems it is not able to recover for intermediate states. As a consequence I must remove the directory and re-start from scratch which does not help in making the branching go further.

Possible issue: my internet connection is not great but it does seems to be the cause. I tried from various location, as well as from a remote hosted VPS: same behavior!

I may try multiple time in a row (removing the folder), it is impossible for it to complete.

How does people branch the emacs trunk repository? Is that a tool(`bzr`) or repository server issue? Do you think it is anyway related to my setup? Bad command?

Comment: What about RAM consumption?  Perhaps it allocates and uses too much.

Comment: @MischaArefiev You're right. From /var/log/syslog : ```Feb 22 12:43:11 xxxxxx kernel: [584519.697873] OOM killed process 21740 (bzr) vm:676940kB, rss:513028kB, swap:88164kB``` . That's just a shame. I will see how do deal with that. Anyway feel free to post a real answer I'll accept it as a gratification!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the process tries to allocate and use too much RAM, and is killed by the kernel after the memory pool is exhausted (you can check `dmesg` for such message).  Googling for «bzr killed out of memory» yields a number of bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/488141
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/456077

I guess you can try a machine with more RAM as a workaround, or, if it is a repository format issue (such as mentioned in the bug reports above) perform the steps suggested in comments to these reports.